# Intermittent NullReferenceException when closing WPF application

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a WPF application with a third party chart control hosted in a `WindowsFormsHost`. When the application is closed a `NullReferenceException` is intermittently thrown (about one in every ten closes).

We are plotting real time data on the chart. For plotting we are using `Control.Invoke`.

Here is the stack trace of the exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RegisterICompositionTargetInternal(ICompositionTarget iv)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget..ctor(IntPtr hwnd)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Initialize(HwndSourceParameters parameters)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Does it crash also when removing completly the control? Have you tried to manually dispose/free the object?

Comment: No, I have not tried to manually dispose/free the object. I have one guess that when we close the application there may be some invokes left to plot, but i have already added a check               if (this.InvokeRequired && this.IsHandleCreated) { this.Invoke(plotChartDelegate, data, null); }